# Apply Python syntax highlighting for the [sage] tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

Could **Python syntax highlighting** be applied by default
to **questions tagged [sage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sage)**? This tag is for SageMath,
the Sage Mathematics Software System, which is Python-based
free software for mathematics.

One objection to the initial version of this question was
that Sage includes R for statistical computation. Indeed,
Sage includes many software components, programmed and
interfaced in a wide variety of programming languages.
That said, SageMath itself **uses Python as its language**,
so that users do not have to know all the programming and
interface languages of all the software Sage uses.

At the user level, in Sage, everything happens in Python
(with a tiny bit of extra syntactic sugar, but there is
no dedicated syntax highlighting mode for that, and Python
syntax highlighting would be the most appropriate for
Sage questions).

More detail about these language questions is provided in the
[sage tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sage/info).

Note: [GitHub applies Python syntax highlighting to files with extension `.sage` or `.sagews`](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/402ff3e42bd93362727ab9083f66239b008ea29d/lib/linguist/languages.yml#L5025).

Note: I initially posted this request after about a week of answering
questions tagged [sage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sage) on Stack Overflow, very enthusiastic and
optimistic about improving things. The many downvotes to my question
and to @kcrisman's answer in support of it, without many explanatory
comments, came as a shock and felt unwelcoming to me as a newcomer,
but may simply have meant my request was poorly formulated; hopefully
it is better argued now.

Note: @kcrisman is the
[number one all-time answerer of Sage questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sage/topusers)
and the [number two all-time answerer on the dedicated Ask Sage questions and answers website](https://ask.sagemath.org/users/).

Comment: Why not also use the tag `python` for such posts then?

Comment: Also, Sage includes R for statistical computations; defaulting to Python highlighting would be a mistake. Sage is not exclusively Python.

Comment: However, Sage *code* is essentially Python.  Any question about Sage that included R would have to include at least some Python-ish code.

Comment: It's not `python` because it's Sage.  There is additional preparsing and lots and lots of additional stuff - Python people answering Sage posts often make a mess of it by complaining "so-and-so isn't a Python command, where did you get it from" when it is a built-in in Sage (via `from sage.all import *` and a few other things).

Comment: @kcrisman: Well, in regular Python, `import *` is [frowned upon](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) to begin with, for precisely this reason.  The NumPy people are perfectly happy using `import numpy as np`...

Comment: In regular Python, things like `f(x)=x^2` aren't valid syntax, either, but they are in Sage (as appropriate).  Sage is not "just" a Python library or module.  However, (nearly) every change that isn't Python is something that would be a Python syntax error but is allowed in Sage (for good mathematical or long-standing math convention reasons).  Sage is happy to encourage numerical users to `import numpy as np`, but for a lot of mathematics, it will not suffice to just use souped-up Python.  `1/3` is wrong, mathematically, in Python 2 *and* Python 3 - just wrong in different ways.

Comment: @Kevin - and so your comment really proves the point that Sage should have its own tag, and yet the syntax highlighting might as well be Python.

Comment: Syntax highlighting is extremely important to spot syntax errors – many "typo" questions can be answered by a comment akin to "check how SO highlights your string literal wrongly". Using Python highlighting for code that is *not* a subset of Python seems misleading, since it will include many false negatives. Are syntax questions/issues common for Sage?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is very reasonable.  However, a prerequisite would be creating a clear tag for the SAGE accounting software, or consistently retagging such questions when they are mistagged.  Apparently sage-erp is now being used at least occasionally - see [Sage accounting software tag as opposed to sagemath](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139946/sage-accounting-software-tag-as-opposed-to-sagemath) and sagepay for a similar UK software.

Comment: Separate tags have been created for the Sage accounting software
and for the Sage Wordpress plugin. See links in the
[sage tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sage/info).